# PHP: Reading Excel file skips empty rows (using spreadsheet-reader)

Tags: php, excel

I am using [nuovo/spreadsheet-reader](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader) to read excel files. When reading in XLSX files, the first row as well as all rows that contain no data are skipped. The following rows are then placed in the skipped rows' index. For example, if the spreadsheet has 10 rows, of which 2 rows have no data, parsing all the cells as follows:

```
$excel_obj = new SpreadsheetReader($file);
// Sheet is changed to the correct one, not shown here

foreach ($excel_obj as $key => $row)
{
    error_log("key:".$key); // This only prints for each non empty row
    if ($row)
    {
        $form_data[] = $row;
    }
    else
    {
        error_log("example allowed for this case, not sure why - never happens though");
    }
}
```

results in $form_data having 7 rows, indexed 0 to 6 (instead of 10 rows indexed 0 to 9). This would not be as big of an issue if the row indexes were not compromised ($form_data still has 10 row indexes, but 3 does not contain any row data). Unfortunately as it is, it is impossible to reconstruct the original data matrix. Is there another way of reading the data that I am missing, or maybe a proposed fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the missing rows are due to a naive implementation of the XML parser. The XML tags for rows have row number as attribute. spreadsheet-reader does not check for missing rows, instead just pushes new tags as it finds them.

In the end I had to adjust the library to fill in the missing rows.